# CSV Contain No In formation

Tags: magento-1.9, csv

I download Order information But in that csv no information what mistake i made
How to download csv with data

```
public function downloadAction(){
  $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
  $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderId);
    // prepare CSV header
    $csv = '';
    $_columns = array(
     "Order Id",
     "Product Name",
     "Sku",
     "Price");
    $data = array();
    // prepare CSV header...
    foreach ($_columns as $column) {
           $data[] = '"'.$column.'"';
    }
    $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
             $items = $order->getAllItems();
             foreach ($items as $item) {
                   $loadProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                   //prepare csv contents
                    $data[] = $order->getId();
                    $data[] = $loadProduct['name'];
                    $data[] = $loadProduct['sku'];
                    $data[] = $loadProduct['price'];

                    $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
                   //now $csv varaible has csv data as string
        }
    }

    try {
            //download
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('file-'.$orderId.'.csv', $csv, 'text/csv');
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('File downloaded.'));
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $response = array(
                'error'     => true,
                'message'   => $e->getMessage(),
            );
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('sales')->__('File cannot be donwloaded.'));
            $response = array(
                'error'     => true,
                'message'   => $this->__('File cannot be downloaded.')
            );
        }
}

        public function getDownloadCsv($id)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('adminhtml/order/download', array('id' => $id));
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
  public function downloadAction()
  {
      $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
      $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderId);
        // prepare CSV header
        $csv = '';
        $_columns = array(
         "Order Id",
         "Product Name",
         "Sku",
         "Price");
        $data = array();
        // prepare CSV header...
        foreach ($_columns as $column) {
               $data[] = '"'.$column.'"';
        }
        $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";

        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
               $product = $item->getProduct();
               //prepare csv contents
                $data[] = $order->getIncrementId();
                $data[] = $product->getName();
                $data[] = $product->getSku();
                $data[] = $product->getPrice();

                $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
               //now $csv varaible has csv data as string
        }


    try {
            //download
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('file-'.$orderId.'.csv', $csv, 'text/csv');
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('File downloaded.'));
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $response = array(
                'error'     => true,
                'message'   => $e->getMessage(),
            );
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('sales')->__('File cannot be donwloaded.'));
            $response = array(
                'error'     => true,
                'message'   => $this->__('File cannot be downloaded.')
            );
        }
}

        public function getDownloadCsv($id)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('adminhtml/order/download', array('id' => $id));
    }
?>
```

**OR**

```
public function downloadAction()
    {
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderId);
        $header = array('Order Id','Product Name','Sku','Price'); 
        $io = new Varien_Io_File();
        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'export' . DS;
        $name = md5(microtime());
        $file = $path . DS . $name . '.csv';
        $io->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        $io->open(array('path' => $path));
        $io->streamOpen($file, 'w+');
        $io->streamLock(true);
        $io->streamWriteCsv($header);

        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $data = array($order->getIncrementId(), $item->getName(), $item->getSku(), $item->getPrice()); 
            $io->streamWriteCsv($data); 
        }
        $io->streamUnlock();
        $io->streamClose();

        try {
            //download
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('file-'.$orderId.'.csv', file_get_contents($file));
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('File downloaded.'));
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $response = array(
                'error'     => true,
                'message'   => $e->getMessage(),
            );
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('sales')->__('File cannot be donwloaded.'));
            $response = array(
                'error'     => true,
                'message'   => $this->__('File cannot be downloaded.')
            );
        }
  }
```

Comment: error s currently unable to handle this request.

Comment: thanks but order id it shows wrong

Comment: updated ans pls check now\

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: but what is issue in my ans?

Comment: it add once again in order id product name etc..

Comment: it showsfirst product show 2 time second product 1 time

Comment: mean you not need same order id in csv right?

Comment: have you tried second options?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37946/discussion-between-abdul-and-kothari).

Answer (score 1):

Instead loading the product again, why don't you just get order product info from order object itself.

This way, when your product's info is changed after the order, you will get exact same value of ordered items.

Try this:

```
public function downloadAction(){
  $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
  $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderId);
    // prepare CSV header
    $csv = '';
    $_columns = array(
     "Order Id",
     "Product Name",
     "Sku",
     "Price");
    $data = array();
    // prepare CSV header...
    foreach ($_columns as $column) {
           $data[] = '"'.$column.'"';
    }
    $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";

    //you don't have $orders instead have $order and is not array but object
    //foreach ($orders as $order) {
             $items = $order->getAllItems();
             foreach ($items as $item) {
                   //$loadProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                   //prepare csv contents
                    $data[] = $order->getIncrementId();

                    //get product info from order object instead
                    $data[] = $item->getName();
                    $data[] = $item->getSku();
                    $data[] = $item->getPrice();

                    $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
                   //now $csv varaible has csv data as string
        }
    //}

    try {
            //download
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('file-'.$orderId.'.csv', $csv, 'text/csv');
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('File downloaded.'));
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $response = array(
                'error'     => true,
                'message'   => $e->getMessage(),
            );
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('sales')->__('File cannot be donwloaded.'));
            $response = array(
                'error'     => true,
                'message'   => $this->__('File cannot be downloaded.')
            );
        }
}

    public function getDownloadCsv($id)
{
    return $this->getUrl('adminhtml/order/download', array('id' => $id));
}
```

Comment: all field show order id name sku only not value

Comment: I had small bug, check my updated answer. It gives you the item info, but for csv organisation you need to work around.

Comment: it add again column name in field then value

Comment: My order id is this 100001390  but it display 1478

Comment: change $order->getId() to `$order->getIncrementId()`.

Comment: Check my updated question